# Python program doen't finish when using several Gb of RAM

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I'm processing some .csv files with a lot of lines, and I'm having a problem with the ending of my program.

When I launch the program with small csv (3 csv of 1000 lines and 1 of 5.700.000 lines) my program do it's magic in around 21 seconds using around 1.5Gb of memory, when I start using another big csv (2 csv of 1000 and 2 of 5,7 to 5,9 Million lines) it all goes bad in the end.

The program read all the lines, stores them in memory (probably this is not the best way to do this), do all his work (while using around 4Gb and spikes of 7Gb or RAM) and then it finish everything (the last instruction is to write a log info saying that it has ended) but the program doesn't end executing, just keeps there without finishing and without freeing the 4Gb of ram it's been using.

The last lines:

```
with open('insertdata.csv','w',newline='') as csvdat:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvdat,dialect='excel', delimiter=';', quotechar='|')

    for i, data in enumerate(exitlist):
        logger.debug('Start searching rel data for line %s', i)
        try:
        # ---- do things ----
# ---- everything ends here, now it's on the same level as "with open..." ----
logger.info('%s lines inserted into inserdata.csv',n)
if nerror > 0:
    logger.warning('%s document errors found', nerror)

csvlist2 = None
csvlist3 = None
exitlist = None
didlist = None

print("ends")
quit()
```

The last lines of the log:

> 2016-03-31 19:02:19,810 - **main** - ERROR - 
>   '3831414' not found in query3 csv
>
> 2016-03-31 19:02:19,810 - **main** - ERROR - 
>   '3831778' not found in query3 csv
>
> 2016-03-31 19:02:19,810 - **main** - ERROR - 
>   '3831416' not found in query3 csv
>
> 2016-03-31 19:02:19,810 - **main** - INFO - 955 lines inserted into
>   inserdata.csv
>
> 2016-03-31 19:02:19,810 - **main** - WARNING - 45
>   document errors found

The error is a controlled exception, I thought that if the last iteration of the loop what the exception, it can be the problem, but in my last test it wasn't the problem.
As you can see, yesterday at 19:02 it finished, but today at 8:44 am I manually finished the python program from the cmd after all the night "working".

Can it be a problem with using that huge amount of RAM? 
BTW I'm using gc.collect() after a hundred lines to free the space of the deleted entries (I use dictionaries and when used I delete the keys from them) but this happened the same before using it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you need all lines in memory at once?

Comment: I don't know another way to do it, but what I'm doing is merging the data of the 4 csv in one, so for every line of the first one, I search in the other 3 and get the data. EDIT(pressed intro before time):  Maybe I can do it one csv at a time and then clearing it...

Comment: Deleting all the keys in a dictionary does not necessarily reclaim the memory used by the keys, reassign to an empty dictionary instead.  You can use `shelve` from the standard library to store dictionaries on disk, but of course its slower.  https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shelve.html

Comment: It's not what you ask for, but maybe you can remove the duplicate lines much easier by using command line tools. use `cat` to merge the files into a single file, use `sort` to sort the lines, and use `uniq` to filter out the duplicate lines (?)

Comment: Profile your program processing some csv file it can handle with the `cProfile` module and see where it spends most of it's time. Optimize those areas or add logging to the those sections so you can determine where it's hanging-up on the files it can't process.

Comment: Using debug level logging I can see when it read every line of every csv and when it goes to search in the 4 dictionaries. Right now, the time itself is not much in that, but in finishing the program after it has executed the last instruction (and in the log it's visible that it's been executed) I'll try using profiles, thanks!

Comment: I can't understand how the program reaches and executes the last line and yet it doesn't finish. Unless it is inside a loop or you are using threads or something.

Comment: I added more code. As you can see, it does a loop inside a "with" and then exits all, print to log, put things to None (that's new) and try to force and end to everything(used to be sys.exit() but that didn't do anything and I changed).